# Converting Input.GetAxis to touch screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just created a pong game in Unity using C#. It works on computer but I would also like it to work on my Windows Phone. I believe that I have to change the `Input.GetAxis` to some kind touch control but I don't know how to do

I'll post my code here for the paddle. The other paddle is an AI.

```
public float PaddleSpeed = 1;
public Vector3 PlayerPos;

void Update ()
{
    float yPos = gameObject.transform.position.y + (Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") * PaddleSpeed);
    PlayerPos = new Vector3 (-315, Mathf.Clamp (yPos, -148,148),0);
    gameObject.transform.position = PlayerPos;
}
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. If it's simple UI buttons, there is plenty of information about those. If it's hooking it up to the location of a touch, then look at the Input.touches[].

Comment: I would like to have when you touch the paddle and drag your finger the paddle moves with the finger. I'll check the Input.touches

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add some conditional compiler directives. See this page:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html

So:

```
#if UNITY_WP8
   // touch code for windows phone 8
#else
    // any other platform
#endif
```

For your touch input you should go with @Bart's comment.